# zsh -x but don't show the full path

Tags: shell, debugging, zsh, prompt, oh-my-zsh

Let's assume I have a script:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
myfunc() {
    echo Hello
}
uptime
myfunc
```

And I run it with `zsh -x $PWD/script.sh`, I get the following output:

```
$ zsh -x $PWD/script.sh
+/Users/username/.zshenv:8> [[ 2 -eq 1 ]]
+/Users/username/so/script.sh:5> uptime
20:12  up 2 days,  1:04, 7 users, load averages: 4.09 3.65 3.42
+/Users/username/so/script.sh:6> myfunc
+myfunc:1> echo Hello
Hello
```

I would prefer that instead of printing the full path to the script, just the basename are used, similarly to how the function name is shown.  Desired output:

```
$ zsh -x $PWD/script.sh
+.zshenv:8> [[ 2 -eq 1 ]]
+script.sh:5> uptime
20:12  up 2 days,  1:04, 7 users, load averages: 4.09 3.65 3.42
+script.sh:6> myfunc
+myfunc:1> echo Hello
Hello
```

I know I can cause this to happen by doing e.g. `zsh -x myscript` and not providing the full path, but lots of scripts are run by their full path, when they are in `$PATH`.  Often I debug scripts via `zsh -x =scriptname` where the `=` modifier causes the full path to be expanded.

Are there any `set` options, environment variables, or additional flags that I can pass such that `zsh -x` only shows the basename of the script?  Or any additional way to customize the output of `zsh -x` would be really useful.

Answer (score 2):

The value printed out when using `zsh -x` (also known as the option `XTRACE`) takes a format specifier from the environment variable `$PS4`.  The [documentation on ZSH options](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html) states:

> XTRACE (-x, ksh: -x)
> Print commands and their arguments as they are executed. The output is preceded by the value of $PS4, formatted as described in Prompt Expansion.

It looks like your `PS4='+%N:%i> '`

There are many prompt expansion variables you can use, and you can find them in the [Prompt Expansion documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html).

To get the result you want, you need to set e.g.:

```
$ export PS4="+%1N:%i> "
# or
$ export PS4="+%1N:%I> "
```

The former keeps the default line number behavior, but the latter shows the actual line numbers of the function being executed, which I find very useful.  Instead of showing `myfunc:1` it would show `myfunc:3` since it's line 3 of the file that contains `myfunc`.

The output would then look like:

```
$ zsh -x $PWD/script.sh
+.zshenv:8> [[ 2 -eq 1 ]]
+script.sh:5> uptime
20:25  up 2 days,  1:17, 7 users, load averages: 3.22 3.58 3.49
+script.sh:6> myfunc
+myfunc:3> echo Hello
Hello
```